# uitableview cell highlight

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

I have a table view in which each cell contains a button. I dont use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate but my custom method for the button action. I want that on clicking the button inside each cell, that cell should be highlighted or change colour and return to its normal state(colour) when the button in some other cell is clicked(making this cell highlighted).My button action method is:

```
- (void)SelectButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{


    self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    AppDelegate *proDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;

    //MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)button.superview.superview;

     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [homeTable indexPathForCell:cell];


     //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


    //[homeTable setNeedsDisplayInRect:[homeTable rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];


    DetailViewController *objDetail=[[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    Home *tempSearchObj=(Home *)[profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    objDetail.firstName=tempSearchObj.userName;


    objDetail.userImageUrl=tempSearchObj.imageUrl;

    objDetail.passedProfileID = tempSearchObj.profileID;

    plsSelectLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",objDetail.firstName];

    proDel.globalName = plsSelectLabel.text;

    proDel.globalProfileId = objDetail.passedProfileID;


}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Set the cell selection style in cellForRowAtIndexPath as :

```
if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
    }
```

And :

```
yourButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Add the following line in your method to highlight the cell :

```
UIButton *clickButton = (UIButton *)sender;

int addButtonIndex = clickButton.tag;

NSIndexPath *indexPathHighlight = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:addButtonIndex inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *newCell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathHighlight];

[newCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
```

Unselect previous cell :

```
NSIndexPath *previousIndexPathHighlighted = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:previousTag inSection:0];

UITableViewCell *previousCell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndexPathHighlighted];

[previousCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];

previousTag = clickButton.tag;
```

Comment: This will make the cell highlighted when clicked on the cell, but i want this on click of a button which is a subview of the cell

Comment: @user1845209 You can create the reference of cell in your method if you add tag to your button as indexPath.row when adding the button.

Comment: The above code makes all of the cells selected when i click the button for each..i want that when i click the button on any cell, only that cell should be highlighted and the previously selected cell should come to the normal unhighlighted state

Comment: @user1845209 For that create a loop and inside that create reference of all cell in your table and make that unselected. Or store the previous button tag and unselect that cell only in your method.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to go about this is that on your `cellForRowAtIndex:` method you have a way of knowing if your cell needs to look highlighted or not. Then, after clicking on a button and configuring whatever you need to do, you should simply do

```
NSArray *indexes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

The other way to go about this, is to access the cell and change it directly. But not with `button.superview.superview`, but rather

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
```

Comment: Bu my table rows are dynamic, they are loaded from nsmutableArray and this array can expand or shrink anytime the web service changes, so indexPathForRow:0 is not the way to go i think

Comment: that was just an example ... you should be able to know which cell you are on after clicking a button

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to make a

```
NSInteger selectedCellIndex;
```

---

Set the tags of your buttons in the cellForRowAtIndex method

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

---

Set the selectedCellIndex when you click the button and reload the table

```
selectedCellIndex = button.tag;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

---

Then in the cellForRowAtIndex method check if the index is the same as the selectedCellIndex and add a different color to the cell.

```
if( indexPath.row == selectedCellIndex ){
    //set different colors
}
```

Remember to do this outside the if( cell == nil ) check, otherwise it wouldn't work.